# How to correctly close a connection with Poco::HTTPSClientSession?

Tags: c++, https, connection, poco-libraries, termination

I run into a problem with `Poco::HTTPSClientSession` and don't know how to handle it.

#### Description (or what happens)

A HTTPS connection to a server is established with the use of the `Poco::HTTPSClientSession` class.  Connection establishment, key-exchange, initial data exchange works well.

The client sends one request directly after the session establishment.  The HTTP 1.1 feature persistent connections is used (i.e. the connection remains open for some time to handle additional requests).  The server waits one minute - no further requests are received over this connection - then sends a `close_notify` and closes the connection (with a TCP FIN).  About two minutes after this the client wants to send the next request.  The client sends out a `close_notify` and closes the connection with a TCP RST.

#### My Opinion

The client behavior is IMHO not correct. As you can read in [RFC 6101 5.4.1. Closure Alerts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#section-5.4.1), the other side should close the connection *immediately*:

> It is required that the other party respond with a close_notify alert of its own and close down the connection immediately, discarding any pending writes.

#### My Question

I'm not sure how to handle this with Poco. For me it looks that there is the need for some callback handling (at the point of time when the server sends the `close_notify`).  The problem is, that because the 'socket()' method is protected within the `Poco::HTTPSClientSession` there is no way to install such a `close_notify` handler - and even I don't know if there is a appropriate callback for this.

Can you please hint me to the class / function to use to correctly close the HTTPS connection of the client when the server sends a `close_notify`? [Addition after the answer from Joachim Pileborg]: Is there the need to inherit from `Poco::HTTPSClientSession` to correctly handle the `close_notify`?

Kind regards - Andreas

Comment: Why not simply destruct the `HTTPSClientSession` object when you're done with the request? When you need to make another request create a new one.

Comment: This is because there are also time with high load when some hundreds requests are send out in some seconds. It is not predictable when this happens. For these times the overhead of establishing a SSL connection each time is to high.

Comment: Then have your own timeout? If nothing is requested for more than a set time (seconds? minutes? Up to you) then destroy the object.

Comment: Sorry - but I don't want to go for a workaround. My question is: How to correctly handle this scenario with Poco? To have some (artificially) timeout handling here does not really help me. (And even each server can have another timeout period.) There should be some functionality build in the library to handle these asynchronous close_notifies.

Comment: The problem with getting notified about a closed connection, is that the only way to really tell if a connection have been nicely closed by the other peer is to receive from the socket, which will then return zero bytes received. So it's very hard to handle this asynchronously in a platform-independent way.

Comment: (continued) What most programs does is to check (either by direct polling through `select` or similar, or by having separate thread doing it) if the socket is readable which it will be when the connection has been closed from the other end, and call an "onRead" handler that notices that the connection has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but since there is not any acceptable response I put here my solution if it can help some one.

Do this before sending request to server.

```
if (mySession->socket().poll(0, Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_READ) && (mySession->socket().receiveBytes(NULL,0) == 0)) {
    mySession->reset();
}
```

From Poco documentation :

```
bool poll(const Poco::Timespan& timeout, int mode) const;
    /// Determines the status of the socket, using a 
    /// call to select().
    /// 
    /// The mode argument is constructed by combining the values
    /// of the SelectMode enumeration.
    ///
    /// Returns true if the next operation corresponding to
    /// mode will not block, false otherwise.

int receiveBytes(void* buffer, int length, int flags = 0);
    /// Receives data from the socket and stores it
    /// in buffer. Up to length bytes are received.
    ///
    /// Returns the number of bytes received. 
    /// A return value of 0 means a graceful shutdown 
    /// of the connection from the peer.
    ///
    /// Throws a TimeoutException if a receive timeout has
    /// been set and nothing is received within that interval.
    /// Throws a NetException (or a subclass) in case of other errors.
```

The poll method with select_read mode will return true if you have an open readable socket.
Use receiveBytes to read the server side graceful shutdown and then reset the socket for next requests.